# Deleting rows in MySQL inside one table using timestamp condition

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp, delete-row

I have 10 GB tabel event in MYSQL database. It is part of web application server. Logging in this database wasn't configured well previously, so I need to make one singe table 'event' thinner. 
What I mean is I have data points values logs (rows) and timestamp of this value. 
I can not delete all, I neeed to be able to create chart from values which will stay in this table. That is why I need to leave some representive data.

One idea is to delete rows with same datapId when ts diff is smaller than X or maybe it supposed to be build in on pointValues diff?

Please help me to construct proper query.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>datapId</th>
    <th>dataType</th>
    <th>pointValue</th>
    <th>ts</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>5194</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>15060882793523</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>5194</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1.1</td>
    <td>15060882793524</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>5194</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2.25</td>
    <td>15060882793560</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5194</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2.23</td>
    <td>15060882793590</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>5194</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>15060882793620</td>
  </tr>
  
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, one approach might be to try and build a table with average values of the data:

Try this (creating test data):

```
CREATE TABLE data
(
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
  datapId INT,
  dataType INT,
  pointValue FLOAT,
  ts BIGINT
);

INSERT INTO data VALUES (NULL,5194,1,1,15060882793523);
INSERT INTO data VALUES (NULL,5194,1,1.1,15060882793524);
INSERT INTO data VALUES (NULL,5194,1,2.25,15060882793560);
INSERT INTO data VALUES (NULL,5194,1,2.23,15060882793590);
INSERT INTO data VALUES (NULL,5194,1,0,15060882793620);
```

To build a table averaging the values on `@interval_count` intervals:

```
-- TODO: Manually set interval count
SET @interval_count := 10;
-- Find ts bounds from data
SELECT @ts_min := min(ts) FROM data;
SELECT @ts_max := max(ts) FROM data;
SELECT @interval_size := (@ts_max-@ts_min)/(@interval_count-1);

SELECT 
  -- ts at center of range with width @interval_size
  ts_c as ts_mean, 
  -- Average of values in this range
  AVG(d.pointValue) as pointValue_mean
FROM 
(
  -- Table with equally spaced ts points at range center
  SELECT DISTINCT 
    -- ts value in the middle of the averaging range
    ROUND((ts-@ts_min)/@interval_size)*@interval_size+@ts_min as ts_c 
    -- Lower bound for averaging range
    ,ROUND((ts-@ts_min)/@interval_size)*@interval_size+@ts_min-@interval_size/2
    -- Upper bound for averaging range
    ,ROUND(1+(ts-@ts_min)/@interval_size)*@interval_size+@ts_min+@interval_size/2
  FROM data
) d_c
JOIN data d ON d.ts BETWEEN -- Self join to calculate average in ranges
  ROUND((ts_c-@ts_min)/@interval_size)*@interval_size+@ts_min-@interval_size/2 AND
  ROUND((ts_c-@ts_min)/@interval_size)*@interval_size+@ts_min+@interval_size/2
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```

No idea if this works on 10 GB.

You can try it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/612cf/1

Comment: Finally I decided to do this following way, to have less rows, but to not compute average from data. I listed all data point id which has most values and I delete all even(based on table autoincremented indexes) recrods from database.pointvalues where dataPointId='X' and (id % 2) = 0;